How to get incoming call information on Android
I am building mobile application on the Android.
I need to get a incoming call information on the Android device.
For lower level than api 31, and higher than api 31, How can I do this?
Please help me. I am new in Android
I tried using broadcastreceiver, but broadcastreceiver is deprecated on api 31.
then I tried using connectionservice, but I was not able to get the incoming call.

Have you tried android.telecom.CallScreeningService on api 31 and above??

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Add Permissions to AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Create a PhoneStateListener to listen for phone call state changes.
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;

import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
public class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
private static final String TAG = "CallStateListener";

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d(TAG, "onCallStateChanged: Call ended");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.d(TAG, "onCallStateChanged: Incoming call from " + incomingNumber);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Log.d(TAG, "onCallStateChanged: Call picked up");
            break;
    }
}

}
In your Activity or Service, register the PhoneStateListener with the TelephonyManager.
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();

        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop listening for phone state changes
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
}

Handle Runtime Permissions (For Android 6.0 and above)
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            // Permission has already been granted
            initialize();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted
                initialize();
            } else {
                // Permission denied
                // Handle accordingly
            }
        }
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // Initialize TelephonyManager and register CallStateListener
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}

